# Regarding markovs inequality

Tags: probability

If I know that X is symmetricly distributed with mean 0, can the absolute value be dropped in the inequality?

Comment: Can you please state the exact version of Markov's Inequality that you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could drop it, but you'd get a statement that is unnecessarily weak.

Because $X$ is symmetric about $0$,
\begin{align*} P(|X| > k \sigma) &= P(X > k \sigma \text{ or } X < -k \sigma) \\ &= P(X > k) + P(X  < -k \sigma) \\ & = 2 P(X > k). \end{align*}

Markov's Inequality therefore gives you that $2 P(X > k) \leq \frac{1}{k^2} \implies P(X > k) \leq \frac{1}{2 k^2}.$

If you instead just drop the absolute value on Markov's Inequality, you'll get $P(X > k) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$ which is true, but less informative.